# enviar correos desde flask con archivos pdf adjunto

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar pero mas que eso me orienten para entenerder cual es mi error soy nuevo en flask y en progamación, les cuento estoy haciendo un pagina donde los usuarios pueden descargar pdf y enviar un correo y adjuntar ese mismo pdf que se acaba de descargar, bueno ya pude generar los pdf y los descargo y envio los correos desde Thread para evitar la demora de los envios con esto tengo el siguiente codigo en main.py:

```
import logging
from smtplib import SMTPException
from threading import Thread
from flask import current_app
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        try:
            mail.send(msg)
        except SMTPException:
            logger.exception("Ocurrió un error al enviar el email")
            
def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body,
               cc=None, bcc=None, html_body=None, attachments=None):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients, cc=cc, bcc=bcc)
    msg.body = text_body
    with msg.open_resource(attachments) as fp:
        msg.attach(attachments, "file/pdf", fp.read())
    if html_body:
        msg.html = html_body
    Thread(target=_send_async_email, args=(current_app._get_current_object(), msg)).start()
```

y ese envia los correo pero resulta que revisando un poco la documentacion y es lo que entiendo dice que le pase el adjunto con un with se lo paso pero ahora me da un error que dice que asi:

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'open_resource'
```

como ejecuto la función para enviar los correos la llama de la siguiente manera:

```
print_html = render_template('certificados/certificado.html', ced=cedula, img=image, fecha=strfecha,
                                    name=name)
        
        options={
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': '15',
            'margin-right': '25',
            'margin-left': '20',
            'margin-bottom': '5',
            'zoom': '1.1',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
           }

        # Convertimos el html a nuestro pdf sin guardarlo en el servidor
        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(print_html, False, options=options)

        correo = "correo@destinatario.com"
        name = "Pedrito cañawate"
        # Enviar correo electronico
        send_email(subject='Correo de la intranet',
                       sender=current_app.config['DONT_REPLY_FROM_EMAIL'],
                       recipients=[correo, ],
                       text_body=f'Hola {name}, Bienvenido a tu plataforma',
                       html_body=f'<p>Hola <strong>{name}</strong>, Gracias por hacer parte de la comunidad</p>',
                       attachments=pdf)

        # Convitimos los datos pdf a binarios
        file = BytesIO(pdf)

        filename = "Reglamento.pdf"
        # Descargamos el archivo al navegador
        return send_file(file, attachment_filename=filename, mimetype='application/pdf', as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=-1)
```

La funcion renderiza un html y lo convierto despues a pdf y por utlimo lo trato de adjuntar al correo que voy a enviar no se si estoy haciendo algo mal y por que me sale ese error, gracias de antemano espero me puedan ayudar amigos.